# Rectangle as a root element in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I use Qt 5.5.0 MSVC 2013, 32bit.
I want to create minimal QtQuick application. When I choose `New Project - Qt Quick Application` I got project with 2 QML files: *main.qml* and *MainForm.ui.qml*. Since I do not need them, I delete second one and paste following to *main.qml*:

```
Import QtQuick 2.4

Rectangle{
    id: root
    visible: true
    color: "gray"
    width: 400
    height: 800
}
```

But when I run project I got nothing. I see application in *Task Manager* but there is no application window.
**Question:** Is it possible to create .qml file with Rectangle as a root element?

Comment: Answer: yes, it is possible. Read Qt documentation and start with some basic samples.

Comment: I believe at you're going to need a Window.

Comment: There's a good chance this is a duplicate..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Solution](https://forum.qt.io/topic/58562/solved-rectangle-as-root-element-in-qml-file) was found at official Qt Forum.

> The template for creating **Qt Quick Application** adds `QQmlApplicationEngine` to launch the QML. But `QQmlApplicationEngine` dont work directly with *Rectangle* or *Item* as root element but requires any window like *Window* or *ApplicationWindow*.
>   So to make it work for *Rectangle* use `QQuickView` instead of `QQmlApplicationEngine`.

I changed content of **main.cpp** to

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView *view = new QQuickView;
    view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));

    view->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

and it solved my problem.