# Qt issues : Qt creator run with no result and no errors

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

i'm trying to run this simple Qt  qml application , but it's still compiling with no result and with no errors
ps: this is not the first time facing this problem
i am using Q6 with minGW compiler

Main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.4

Item {
    id: item1
    visible: true

    width: 800
    height: 600

    ScrollView {
        id: frame
        clip: true
        anchors.fill: parent
        ScrollBar.vertical.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        Flickable {
            contentHeight: 2000
            width: parent.width
            Rectangle {
                id : rectangle
                color: "#a7c4c6"
                radius: 6
                anchors.fill: parent
            }
        }
    }

}
```

if anyone could , i'll be very thankfull

Comment: you probably have to replace `Item` with `Window`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32392070/rectangle-as-a-root-element-in-qml) answer too.

Comment: If you need to use `Item`, follow [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickview.html#details), which I found in the thread linked in the answer provided by @folibis, and this is not related to the problem you had with `Window`, this is a new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues with the code snippet:

1. ScrollView and the Flickable are doing the same thing, having both is overkill
2. Flickable should set width, height (can be directly or indirectly via anchoring)
3. Flickable should also set contentWidth, contentHeight
4. Rectangle should not have `anchors.fill: parent` the concept of a Flickable-Rectangle is that the Rectangle can and should have different dimensions than the Flickable

Here's an example with the above recommendations applied:

```
    Flickable {
        id: flickable
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentWidth: rectangle.width
        contentHeight: rectangle.height
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            width: 20
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        }
        Rectangle {
            id : rectangle
            implicitWidth: 300
            implicitHeight: 300
            width: implicitWidth
            height: implicitHeight
            color: "#a7c4c6"
            radius: 6
        }
    }
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAACVXicbVFBTsMwELz7FatwtyIoJeRWKlXcoHDgvHXSeFXXjhyHqEL5O06prThiT/bM7OysTefWWAd7t+9JnBglV7412lmjOvaOTQ0/DHwdUJwaa3pdlfBRC4e6UZ4DYZSxJWR3xaoonh8zGK/ynfJGeFChfSryrceARxS1kMZ2/EhKldCirbWLpPBJ/P2LKidLsGEuHyZgqXqtqZFuLpNXJOo+hd9KvaDl37V1JNAPjNgs6FTD38j7PEFb4/NfZl18owa8dG86ysZ4mj1TYkIVzEKm1Ln1Aygs/JDn/9Jh0yV/C524JAJ5a0yNEkn8UHwSK7HOEtJiRX1Xwnqx7shGxn4BIoamVQ==)

In addition, I agree with other comments that for an application the root item typically is a Window or ApplicationWindow.